# Outlook contacts

Tags: sync

I have managed to synch my outlook email and calendar with android, but it is not synching my contacts.  Naturally this is a real bore!
I have checked in my accounts settings and it is saying that it is synched, but my contacts are not showing on my android device.
I do not want to do a csv export as I want them to be continually updating - any tips?

Answer (score 0):

They are probably synchronized but not visible in contacts, try looking into Contacts settings something about contacts to visualize, or accounts.